# Angle between tangents to the curve $x^2+3y^2=9$

Tags: conic-sections, tangent-line

> Tangents drawn from the point $(\alpha,\alpha^2)$ to the curve $x^2+3y^2=9$ include an acute angle between them, then find $\alpha$.

My attempt is by using the equation for pair of tangents from an external point to the curve. If the curve is $S=0$ then the equation for pair of tangents is $SS_1=T^2$, where $S_1=0$ is obtained after putting the external point in $S=0$. And $T=0$ is obtained after changing $x^2$ to $xx_1$ and $y^2$ to $yy_1$ in $S=0$, where $(x_1,y_1)$ is the external point from which the tangents are being drawn.

So,

$$SS_1=T^2$$
$$\implies (x^2+3y^2-9)(\alpha^2+3\alpha^4-9)=(x\alpha+3y\alpha^2-9)^2$$

Now, if $\theta$ is the angle between the tangents then $\tan\theta=|\frac{2\sqrt{h^2-ab}}{a+b}|$, where, $2h=$ coefficient of $xy=6\alpha^3, a=$ coefficient of $x^2=3\alpha^4-9$ and $b=$ coefficient of $y^2=3\alpha^2-27$

Therefore, $\tan\theta=|\frac{2\sqrt{9\alpha^6-9(\alpha^4-3)(\alpha^2-9)}}{3\alpha^4+3\alpha^2-36}|=|\frac{2\sqrt{\alpha^6-(\alpha^6-9\alpha^4-3\alpha^2+27)}}{\alpha^4+\alpha^2-12}|=|\frac{2\sqrt{9\alpha^4+3\alpha^2-27}}{\alpha^4+\alpha^2-12}|$

Not able to proceed next.

Comment: What is $\alpha$ in the cited problem? What does it mean that "tangents **include** an acute angle? (And if they don't, do we still have to find that $\alpha$?) What are $S,S_1,T$ in the attempt?

Comment: @dan_fulea I have made the edit. Also, from the external point, two tangents would be drawn to the ellipse. And those tangents would have an acute angle between them.

Comment: Do you mean that, if $A=(\alpha,\alpha^2)$ if $T$ and $T'$ are the such that the lines $AT$ and $T'$ are tangent to the ellipse, then the angle $\angle T\hat AT'$ is acute?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes.

Comment: Where did this equation $SS_1=T^2$ come from? Please explain.

Comment: Please take time, and edit the question so that objects are introduced in the right order. Please say what is that $\alpha$ **before** using it. The **include** (associated to an angle) is still unclear. Because the **inclusion** makes sense for sets, and some "angle" seen as sector maybe can "include" some other angle". Then start also defining that $S$ and $S_1$ immediately, not in some later EDIT. That $T^2$ still makes no sense. The implication makes no sense, since $S,S_1,T$ have no relation to $x,y,\alpha$ as they stay there.

Comment: @dan_fulea ok, 2 mins.

Comment: From experimentation in geogebra there's a range $\alpha> 1.7$ (and $\alpha< -1.7$) for which the angle is acute.

Comment: @dan_fulea I have explained my solution in order now. Also, the external point is $(\alpha,\alpha^2)$. I have not defined it. It is part of the question. Also, if there are two intersecting lines then they would have an obtuse angle between them and an acute angle. The word 'include' might be wrongly used here, don't know. It's part of the question.

Comment: @TedShifrin that's the equation for pair of tangents from an external point to a curve. I have edited my post. Hopefully things are clearer now.

Comment: As it stays no, the problem is "Tangents drawn from the point $(\alpha,\alpha^2)$..." and here we stop. What is $\alpha$? It seems that the problem is copied / translated from somewhere, as it stays it makes no sense from here, where i am reading it. "Find $\alpha$" is also unclear. But ok. I will let it as it is without downvote and quit here.

Comment: @dan_fulea The external point could be $(2,4)$ or $(5,25)$ or $(\sin4, \sin^24)$. I don't know. Maybe the question setter should have written that $\alpha$ is a real number. But I guess even without that, things are clear enough to start the problem.

Comment: @aarbee pay attention to the comment by Jan-Magnus. An infinite number of values $\alpha$ satisfy.

Comment: @user376343, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Jan-Magnus, thanks.

Comment: $\theta<90°$ for $\alpha>\sqrt3$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thanks. Would you mind elaborating this in an answer so that I could understand the underlining reasoning better? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\alpha^4+\alpha^2-12=(\alpha^2-3)(\alpha^2+4)$ making the angle $\pi/2$ for $\alpha=\pm\sqrt{3}.$

> Now check for say $\alpha\approx 2.2$
>  [image: parabolaellipsetangentsangle]

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful hint but I am still not able to conclude things. In the comments above you have written that for $\alpha\gt\sqrt3$ and $\alpha\lt-\sqrt3$, angle would be acute. How did we decide that? I understand the denominator would be positive for the above range and would be negative otherwise. Does that have anything to do with acuteness or obtuseness of the angle? How? Any other hint would be welcomed, thanks.

Comment: @aarbee You need to check that the square root exists (which it does outside the ellipse), and then it is clear that as $\alpha$ varies the angle changes from obtuse to acute at $\sqrt3$. Then it’s a matter of checking in which direction. Outside the ellipse but close to it the angle is obtuse as you can see by drawing it, or thinking that at the ellipse you start with a double tangent which has angle $\pi$. Far from the ellipse the angle is acute as you can check for a value or by using that the ellipse is bounded and the situation looks like chopsticks about an egg.

Comment: When I put $\alpha=0$, square root become negative, so, not possible. When I put $\alpha=1$ or $-1$, square root exists, but $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ sure lie inside the ellipse. So, can we relate the existence of square root with the point being outside the ellipse? How do we find points which lie outside the ellipse? Also, I understand if the point is just outside the ellipse then the angle will be obtuse. But how do we put a numerical figure to it? I understand at $\alpha=\pm\sqrt3$, angle will be 90, but not able to decide how to go left and right of it. (Thankyou for your engagement.)

Comment: @aarbee $h^2-ab=27(3\alpha^4+\alpha^2-9)$ which has zeros for $\alpha\approx\pm 1.25435$ which does fit with the border of the ellipse.

Comment: Thanks, I had made a mistake in calculating $h^2-ab$, I have edited my post now. But I am sorry I am still not able to see why there would an acute angle for $\alpha\gt\sqrt3$.

Comment: @aarbee See the edit.

Comment: Got it now, thankyou so much.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=mx+c$$ will be tangent of $$\dfrac{x^2}{3^2}+\dfrac{y^2}3=1$$  if $c^2=9m^2+3$

$$(y-mx)^2=c^2=9m^2+3$$

$$ m^2(9-x^2)+2mxy+3-y^2=0$$

As these pass through $(\alpha,\alpha^2),$

$$ m^2(9-\alpha^2)+2m\alpha^3+3-\alpha^4=0$$
which is a quadratic equation in $m$

$$m_1+m_2=-\dfrac{2\alpha^3}{9-\alpha^2}, m_1m_2=\dfrac{3-\alpha^4}{9-\alpha^2}$$

If the angle between the tangents be $p,$

$$\tan p=\left|\dfrac{m_1+m_2}{1-m_1m_2}\right|$$

Comment: But that's not giving us an answer. Or is it?

Comment: The problem is still unclear, but ok, we now have a solution, which is immediately edited. I am just curious: Did the above find that $\alpha$? Where is it?

Comment: @dan_fulea yes, the above solution also gives $\tan\theta$ in terms of $\alpha$, the way I got. But we haven't got $\alpha$ yet.

Comment: So just look at the question as it is **now**. Is that a question? Is that a kind of something having any sense? Now look at your answer. Is there any starting point? Do we have some sentence with a clear meaning? Which is the subject in "As these pass through $(\alpha,\alpha^2)$..." And where do we know that "that stuff" is passing through? You immediately invent $m_1,m_2$, and relate them to some tangents we never saw before, but ok, their angle is $p$, and now we can write some equality connecting the $p$, never known to my eyes, to something that can be written only in terms of $\alpha$...

Comment: @dan_fulea, lab bhattacharjee's solution is a fairly acceptable solution. Everything he has written is in standard format.