# What is the elliptical cone that bounds two ellipsoids

Tags: conic-sections, ellipsoids

I would like to determine the elliptical cone that contains two ellipsoids such that each ellipsoid is tangent to the cone along the corresponding ellipsoid's ellipse (as conic section).

See picture below:

[image]

In particular, if I write the ellipsoids in homogeneous quadratic form, how can I solve for the elliptical cone?

It seems like I should be able to connect the fact that each ray along the elliptical cone is simultaneously tangent to both ellipsoids.  Then for each ellipsoid, these tangent points define a parametric curve that is actually an ellipse from the conic section made by a plane intersecting the cone.

@amd?

Comment: I think such a cone doesn't exist, in general. Do you have any constraints on the ellipsoids?

Comment: I also suppose the ellipsoids are given in position, right? That is, they cannot be translated nor rotated?

Comment: Are you accustomed to work with pencils of quadrics ? The $4 \times 4$ matrix associated with the cone you are looking for can be written $M=\lambda M_1+ (1-\lambda) M_2$ where $M_1,M_2$ are the (positive definite) matrices associated with the ellipsoids ; express that $M$ is the matrix of a cone.

Comment: @jean-marie yes, this is where I ended up.  I followed the Intersection of Two Conics from p.196 here:
Richter-Gebert, Jürgen (2011). Perspectives on Projective Geometry: A Guided Tour Through Real and Complex Geometry.   That allows me to identify the ellipse at the intersection of cone and ellipsoid, one at a time.  Each equation provides two unknowns as the solution of a cubic.  Then I solve these simultaneously for the cone positive definite matrix.  The algebra is pretty complex,  so I hoped someone could outline a really clean strategy

Comment: Maybe you can use the general equation of a cone issued from a given apex to a quadric curve as described in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3926772) ? The apex being a priori unknown...

Comment: Thanks, @JeanMarie! Working through the details now

Comment: @https://math.stackexchange.com/users/305862/jean-marie - can you please send me a reference where I can learn more about the classical form for two intersecting conics that you mentioned (T^2 = S . S1)?  It's not clear to me how this derives from the general expression (C = lamba * A + mu * B, given two intersecting conics A and B).  Would you like to solve the problem statement above for us as a short contract effort?  gareth@thirdinsight.ai

Comment: I am not sure that a common tangent cone exists for any 2 ellipsoids. But if such a cone exists, there is a remark bringing an important simplification : up to a translation and a matricial operation (the translation can be included in the matricial operation if we work with homogeneous coordinates) we may assume that one of the ellipsoids is the unit sphere. 
The translation is easily done. The second operation (getting a sphere) amounts to replace 
$X^TAX$ where $A$ is positive definite by $Y^TY$ where $Y=A^{-1/2}X$. Of course this operation has to be applied to the second ellipsoid too...

Comment: I realized that a comment tangent cone cannot exist between a sphere and a very thin ellipsoid (think to the limit case, a line segment).

Comment: Hi, Jean Marie.  Possible to chat offline?

Comment: @Jean-Marie Let's assume the non-degenerate case (non-zero dimensions for ellipsoids).  Then I think we can select a valid and unique cone for two given ellipsoids?  Again, the formula you showed in your other post (T^2 = S.S1) feels like an extension of a bilinear form.  It would be an additional constraint for each ellipsoid.  Can you guide me to background on this?

Comment: Ughh, @jean-marie, yes, I just realized too that the case of a cone cannot possibly work in general (e.g., sphere and line segment).  I will reframe my question later when I see the correct form/phrasing.

Comment: Beautiful question!